# Loading gif "freezes" when code is executing

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

I'm appending an animated gif which is a loading bar. The gif is defined earlier in the code and I then just do the following..

```
document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "inline";
//some if statements.
do_ajax(params);
```

The ajax call looks something like...

```
    var uri = getURL(params);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST",uri,false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
    xhr.send(null);
```

to show the loading gif. I then perform some checks (if statements) followed by an AJAX request. However, the gif freezes while all this code is executing and only begins to 'move' once the code has finished executing. Why is this? How do I fix this issue?

I'm using Chrome 11

Comment: What browser are you using, and what version? (Guessing the answers wrongly: Internet explorer, all versions (except maybe 9))

Comment: is it a blocking AJAX-call? maybe you should post the whole code.

Comment: I've posted the AJAX code involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using synchronous XHR. This will lock the browser whilst waiting for the request to finish. Obviously, it causes a serious UI issue.

Try asynchronous. Set `open()`'s 3rd parameter to `true`. You also need to assign the `readystatechange` event and listen for success.

[Further Reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Answer (score 3):

I guess just make sure you are using async: true

```
    $("#wait").show(); //SHOW WAIT IMG

     $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        async: true, // <<<<< MAKE SURE IT'S TRUE
        data: { data1: "y", data2: "m", data3: "x" },
        complete: function() {
            $("#wait").hide();
        },        

        success: function(result) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was using sample code for google charts and it has `async: false`, causing this issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting to see the loading.gif while your synchronous ajax request is running?

Synchronous ajax requests completely lock up the UI of most browsers, preventing any changes you make from being displayed until the request completes.

If you want to see loading.gif while the request is running, make it asynchronous:

```
//--- js code

document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "inline";

//--- js code

var uri = getURL(params);
xmlhttp.open("POST", uri, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;
xmlhttp.send(null);
function handleReadyStateChange() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        // Request Complete
    }
}
```