# loading gif freezes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loading gif image which I show until the task is completed however it freezes while ajax call is running. How can make the loading gif not freeze?

```
var dataString = 'subject='+ subject + '&message='+ message;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "message",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() 
    {

        $("#errormsg").html('<div>Please wait <img src="image/loader.gif"/></div>');

    },

    success: function(response)
    {
    $('#errormsg').html(response);  
    }
    });
```

Comment: Get a spinning `gif`. You can get one [here](http://www.ajaxload.info/).

Comment: Do you have an `$.ajaxSetup({async: false})` somewhere?

Comment: @fbynite that's what I have currently. I will reword the last sentence if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading gif "freezes" when code is executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015273/loading-gif-freezes-when-code-is-executing)

Comment: @JohnFx That question had synchronous AJAX. jQuery is asynchronous unless you specify `async: false`.